# Which hedge plants can be used for animal preventive fencing?

Tags: hedge, fence, privacy-plants

For a land with medium rainfall which hedge plant species can be used for creating fence. Plants that should prevent entrance of animals like goats and cows and ideally its leaves should not be edible for herbivores. And they should not require abundance of water. Even great if there are options that produce fruits or other byproduct. Climate varies from 28 to 115°F (-2 to 46°C).

Thinking about [Carissa Carandas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carissa_carandas) but not sure if animals eat it.

Comment: What climate? I am thinking of a cactus fence.

Comment: Climate is not very dry, we have good monsoon rain in July August.

Comment: How big are the animals you want to keep out? For example keeping out rabbits and deer are very different problems.

Answer (score 3):

If you are looking for some low fence against rabbits, planting [Rosa rugosa](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rosa_rugosa) close to each other might be helpful:

> Rosa rugosa (rugosa rose, beach rose, Japanese rose, Ramanas rose, or letchberry) is a species of rose native to eastern Asia, in northeastern China, Japan, Korea and southeastern Siberia, where it grows on beach coasts, often on sand dunes.

On the islands of the [North Sea](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/North_Sea) it is used for that purpose, and you may use the fruits e.g. for [rose hip](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rose_hip) jam.

A traditional central-European concept are the [sunken lanes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sunken_lane) around fields which have hedges on both sides, usually a wide mixture of different plants. Often, [common hazel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Corylus_avellana) and [wild plums](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prunus_americana) of different variations are part of these hedges.

Comment: Thanks for a great suggestion, will go for it if there are no better options.

Answer (score 0):

I like Arborvitae for living hedges. A cultivar like Emerald Green. My customers love them. They won't keep animals out.

Comment: Yes they are beautiful but not suitable for the purpose.